# How to connect to heroku postgres database?

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to connect to postgres databse on heroku but it doesn't work for me.

This is the code in index.php

```
<?php
$host = "my host";
$dbname = "my database name";
$user = "my username";
$password = "my password";
$port = "5432";

$dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;user=$user;port=$port;password=$password";

$db = new PDO($dsn);

if($db){
  echo "Connected <br />".$db;
}else {
  echo "Not connected";
}
 ?>
```

But nothing appear on the screen it should print not connected if the credentials are wrong.

Help Please

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

You need to get your `DATABASE_URL` variable. You can get it going [here](https://data.heroku.com) and press 'View Credentials'. Then fill your DB connection with the info provided.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try next code, it works with me.

```
<?php

   $con = "dbname=fgsfg10pdq host=ghfghfh4654.amazonaws.com port=5432 user=gafasduyiu password=435346af8493196 sslmode=require";


   if (!$con) 
   {
     echo "Database connection failed.";
   }
   else 
   {
     echo "Database connection success.";
   }

?>
```

Comment: I solved it long time ago.. thanks
the problem is you can't connect via localhost. only through heroku server

Comment: Please tell how to connect with SSL in mysqli_connect